# Is there a way of accessing the properties of an object in java by using a string to represent the property's name, just like in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, string, object, properties

In JavaScript you can access a property of an object in two ways:

```
object.property
object["property"]
```

In Java, I am only aware of the first way. Is there a way to access a Java object's properties by using a string as well?

Comment: There is, if you're prepared to go down the dark road of [Java reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html).

Comment: For simple use cases though, you generally don't want to

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, lol, I agree to an extent.  There are some complexities with reflection, although the fundamentals aren't too extraneous.  It's incredibly abstract, in terms of how it's structured, in relation to the general portion of the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not part of the syntax.

[Oracle, Chapter 18 - Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html)

You could use reflection, if that suits your needs.
Java reflection offers the ability to access objects, fields, and methods via `String` values, and other methods, if need be.

Consider the following class.

```java
class Example {
    String string = "stack overflow";

    int method(int valueA, int valueB) {
        return valueA + valueB;
    }
}
```

If you want to access the field `string`, you can use the following.

```java
Example example = new Example();
Field field = example.getClass().getDeclaredField("string");
String string = field.get(example);
```

If you want to call `method`, you can use the following.

```java
Example example = new Example();
Method method = example.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("method", int.class, int.class);
int value = (int) method.invoke(example, 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Apache OGNL language](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html), it is an external dependency that allows you to access properties with names in strings.

It has many more features, but you cannot expect that it simply expands your Java syntax - you will have to evaluate a String that contains an expression in that language.

In some cases you can embed it, like in Apache Camel, where it is "just another expression language".